# $x^{1/n}$ is a positive real number?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Terence Tao, ***Analysis I***, 3e:

> **Lemma 5.6.6.** Let $x,y \ge 0$ be non-negative reals, and let 
>   $n,m \ge 1$ be positive integers.
>
> (a) ...
>
> (b) ...
>
> (c) $x^{1/n}$ is a positive real number.

Statement (c) does not seem correct to me:

Choose $x = 0$. 
Then, by definition, $x^{1/n} = \text{sup}\{ y \in \mathbb{R} : y \ge 0 \; \wedge \; y^n \le 0 \} = \text{sup}\{0\}$. Assume there is a least upper bound $\delta > 0$. Then there is an upper bound $\delta/2$ smaller than $\delta$. This contradicts the assumption that $\delta$ is a least upper bound.

Hence, there is a least upper bound $0$, and I would expect $x^{1/n}$ to be a non-negative real number.

Comment: likely intent was $x,y>0$ not $\ge 0$...

Comment: This is a mistake. It is listed in the errata here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/analysis-i/.  Statement (c) should say “$x^{1/n}$ is a non-negative real number, and is positive if and only if $x$ is positive”.

Comment: Or perhaps the intent was to say that $x^\frac 1n$ is nonnegative. The tendency to confuse nonnegative and positive happens at every level.

Comment: @greelious: Would you mind putting your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give an answer, as greelioushas pointed out in a comment, the [Errata](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/analysis-i/) to the third edition (hardback)
says

> Page 123: Lemma 5.6.6(c) should read “$x^{1/n}$ is a non-negative real number, and is positive if and only if $x$ is positive”.